# how to match keywords in the sentences and listdown the matched sentence python

Tags: python

I have 3 list

```
sentencelist =  ['Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday. Hellow Time. Bus is coming to me. The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants. '
                 ' That txt 2 strike came during an assault by Islamic State fighters. He says the evacuation of refugees from a squalid camp. The sky is blue.'
                 ' This txt 3 African migrant says leaving the camp is not an entirely happy experience. Workers in the house. Apple in the tree']


topwordlist = ['areas city from offensive', ' He sky camp blue',' leaving happy tree migrant']
sentencename_list=['001.txt', '002.txt', '003.txt']
#print topwordlist


listA=zip(sentencename_list,topwordlist ,sentencelist)
print listA
```

by using zip function the listA can combine all the list.

```
listA [(sentencename,topword,sentence),
        (sentencename,topword,sentence),
       (sentencename,topword,sentence)]
```

result:

```
     [("001.txt", "areas city from offensive", "Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday. Hellow Time. Bus is coming to me. The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants."),
("002.txt","He sky camp blue"," That txt 2 strike came during an assault by Islamic State fighters. He says the evacuation of refugees from a squalid camp. The sky is blue."),
("003.txt","leaving happy tree migrant","This txt 3 African migrant says leaving the camp is not an entirely happy experience. Workers in the house. Apple in the tree")]
```

I would like to get the matchSentence where only the sentence consists the topwordlist will be shown. 
For example: the following sentences are the matchSentence

```
 "Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday.",
"The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants.",
"He says the evacuation of refugees from a squalid camp."
" The sky is blue."
"This txt 3 African migrant says leaving the camp is not an entirely happy experience."
"Apple in the tree."
```

I would like to add the new element "matchSentence" to the listA .

```
how to get the following  (sentencename,topword,matchSentence,sentence)
```

for example:

```
[('001.txt', 'areas city from offensive', " Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday." ," Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday. Hellow Time. Bus is coming to me. The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants."),
("001.txt","The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants."," 'Iraqi txt 1  forces shelled areas outside of Mosul Monday. Hellow Time. Bus is coming to me. The offensive to retake the city from Islamic State militants."),
 ("002.txt","..topword..",".matchSentence1...","..sentence.."),
 ("002.txt","..topword..",".matchSentence2...","..sentence.."),
 ("002.txt","..topword..",".matchSentence3...","..sentence.."),
 ("003.txt","..topword..",".matchSentence...","..sentence.."),
 (.....)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to make the matches through **regular expressions**.

```
import re
reg_sentence = re.compile(r'[^\.]+\.')
```

With this, you can get each separated sentence on the string (as long as they end with a `.` char) with:

```
sentences_in_string = reg_sentence.findall(any_string)
```

Then, on each sentence:

```
matched = false
matched_sentences = []
for word in topword.split(' '):
    if word in sentence:
        matched_sentences.append(sentence)
        matched = true
        break
```

These are just examples. But I think you can get what you want if you adapt them to your code. I hope this helps.